# How to perform exploratory factor analysis with complex survey data for ordinal and dichotomous variables?

Tags: factor-analysis, survey, psychometrics, survey-weights

I would like to perform an exploratory factor analysis in R with complex sample survey data involving ordinal and dichotomous variables.

The `svyfactanal()` function from the **survey** package is only able to use the maximum likelihood method, which is inappropriate for non-normal ordinal or dichotomous variables.

If the data at hand had not come from a complex sample, I would use the `polychoric()` function to create a polychoric correlation matrix which would then be used in the `fa()`function of the **psych** package using the iterated principal axis method, however, I'm not sure of how to adapt that procedure for the case of data from a complex sample survey.

I tried the `svycor()` function from the **jtools** package, however it yields a pearson correlation matrix instead of a polychoric correlation matrix.

For example, how could I handle an example using the `api` dataset from the **survey** package with the following factor variables `sch.wide`, `comp.imp`, `stype`, `awards`?

```
library(survey)
library(jtools)
library(psych)

data(api)

dstrat <- svydesign(id = ~1,strata = ~stype, weights = ~pw, data = apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
```

Comment: I think the development version of lavaan might do this. (But only might.)

Comment: Polychoric correlation also assumes the ordinal\binary data is a quantized normal. However, you could use Spearman's $\rho$ or Kendall's $\tau$.